# Regarding Chip Pearson's ReverseArrayInPlace function, how does a user pass an array to the input function in the first place?

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, reverse

In an attempt to learn how to reverse a 1-D array, several Google searches point to Chip Pearson's ReverseArrayInPlace function (see here http://www.cpearson.com/excel/vbaarrays.htm).

```
For Ndx = LBound(InputArray) To ((UBound(InputArray) - LBound(InputArray) + 1) \ 2)
'swap the elements
Temp = InputArray(Ndx)
InputArray(Ndx) = InputArray(Ndx2)
InputArray(Ndx2) = Temp
' decrement the upper index
Ndx2 = Ndx2 - 1
Next Ndx
```

However, as a very novice vba coder, I am confused about two things:

1. How does a user pass a particular range to the InputArray?
2. How would a user print the reversed array to a worksheet? Would they simply print the Temp array?

Answer (score 1):

This is the entire function (minus the part that checks the dimensions of the array).

It needs one parameter that is an array, it can also accept an optional boolean.

```
Public Function ReverseArrayInPlace(InputArray As Variant, _
    Optional NoAlerts As Boolean = False) As Boolean
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' ReverseArrayInPlace
' This procedure reverses the order of an array in place -- this is, the array variable
' in the calling procedure is reversed. This works only on single-dimensional arrays
' of simple data types (String, Single, Double, Integer, Long). It will not work
' on arrays of objects. Use ReverseArrayOfObjectsInPlace to reverse an array of objects.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

Dim Temp As Variant
Dim Ndx As Long
Dim Ndx2 As Long


'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Set the default return value.
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
ReverseArrayInPlace = False

'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' ensure we have an array
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
If IsArray(InputArray) = False Then
    If NoAlerts = False Then
        MsgBox "The InputArray parameter is not an array."
    End If
    Exit Function
End If



Ndx2 = UBound(InputArray)
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' loop from the LBound of InputArray to
' the midpoint of InputArray
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
For Ndx = LBound(InputArray) To ((UBound(InputArray) - LBound(InputArray) + 1) \ 2)
    'swap the elements
    Temp = InputArray(Ndx)
    InputArray(Ndx) = InputArray(Ndx2)
    InputArray(Ndx2) = Temp
    ' decrement the upper index
    Ndx2 = Ndx2 - 1
Next Ndx

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' OK - Return True
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
ReverseArrayInPlace = True

End Function
```

This sub will call the reversing function.

```
Sub test()
    Dim arr(20) As Long
    Dim i As Long

    For i = 0 To 20

        arr(i) = i
        Debug.Print arr(i)
    Next
    Dim success As Boolean
    success = ReverseArrayInPlace(arr)
    Debug.Print success
    For i = 0 To 20
        Debug.Print arr(i)
    Next
End Sub
```

Since arrays are by default passed by reference the original array has been modified, no need to return it.

Comment: *"Since arrays are always passed by reference"* Are you sure? I can pass an array `ByVal`.

Comment: according to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/array-argument-must-be-byref). Though I guess are by default passed ByRef is probably better wording.

Comment: Ah yes, but that is only true if you declare `Dim arr() As Variant`. But if you declare `Dim arr As Variant` and then `arr = Array(1, 2, 3, 4)` and pass this variable `arr` to a procedure `Sub ModArray(ByVal internalArr As Variant)` it won't return a modified array.

Comment: OK *"by default"* is clear now, I just was confused because I was sure I did that before.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ, could you help me understand something...why is it that I can pass a variable range as an array to some value like Dim arr but also to a value like Dim arr()? I am not sure I understand the difference, because won't VBA treat both arr and arr() as arrays?

Comment: @GalenH `Dim arr` is the same as `Dim arr As Variant` so a `Variant` can be everything even an `Object`, `Integer` or an `Array`. If you `Dim arr()` this means it can only be an array. Nothing else. • `Variant` actually means that the variable is of no **specific** type.

Comment: @peh so is it considered best practice to always dim an array as arr() if I know I am only going to use it as an array? Or does it really not matter in the grand scheme?